# Cannot resolve symbol CloudSearchCallback()

Tags: android, cloudboost

I'm working on CloudBoost with android and I need to query some data stored. I can't use this query command : `query.find(new CloudSearchCallback())`.

Android Studio says:

> "Cannot resolve symbol CloudSearchCallback()"

I have ensured that I added necessary libraries like :JavaSDK-1.0.7, okhttp-2.4.0, okhttp-ws-2.4.0, okio-1.4.0, socket-client.

Thanks for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no callback interface called `CloudSearchCallback()` in CloudBoost. However `CloudQuery.find` returns `CloudObject`'s matching your query criteria. So you are supposed to use `CloudObjectArrayCallback` and override the `done` method which returns an `CloudObject[]` if all goes well and/or `CloudException` in case something goes wrong.
Replace your code with something like this:

```
                    query.find(new CloudObjectArrayCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(CloudObject[] x, CloudException e) throws CloudException {
                        if(e!=null)
                            //handle exception
                        else if(x!=null)
                            //process returned records

                    }
                });
```